# How to get at one particular item in JSON file using serde_json without deriving structs?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a complex JSON file and I'd like to extract only a single value out of it. I could define all of the `struct`s and derive `Deserialize` on all of them, but I'd like to just write a little manual code to pull that one value out. The [Serde documentation](https://serde.rs/impl-deserializer.html), quite frankly, just confused me.

My JSON content has the following layout:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "hostname": "a hostname"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking for the value navigated to by going into `data`, then taking the first element of the array, and taking the value of `hostname`.

In Haskell, I'd do it like this:

```hs
newtype Host = Host Text

instance FromJSON Host where
    parseJSON (Object o) = (return . Host) <=< (.: "hostname") <=< (fmap (!! 0) . parseJSON) <=< (.: "data") $ o
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

What's the equivalent for Serde?

Comment: That link is for ppl that want to implement a format deserializer/parser. [This](https://serde.rs/deserialize-map.html) should be what you need.

Comment: https://github.com/serde-rs/json#operating-on-untyped-json-values

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`serde_json` provides types for generic JSON values with [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.htmlb):

```
use serde_json::Value;

// input variable
let input: &str = "{...}";

// parse into generic JSON value
let root: Value = serde_json::from_str(input)?;

// access element using .get()
let hostname: Option<&str> = root.get("data")
    .and_then(|value| value.get(0))
    .and_then(|value| value.get("hostname"))
    .and_then(|value| value.as_str());

// hostname is Some(string_value) if .data[0].hostname is a string,
// and None if it was not found
println!("hostname = {:?}", hostname); // = Some("a hostname")
```

([full playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=1649e0325277ba399693b2ee27045122))

Answer (score 7):

If you are OK with returning `Value::Null` if the value is missing or malformed, I'd use [the `Index` syntax](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.62/serde_json/enum.Value.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E) (`[...]`). If you want to handle the missing / malformed case differently, use the [`get`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.62/serde_json/enum.Value.html#method.get) method:

```
fn main() {
    let json_value = serde_json::json!({
      "data": [
        {
          "hostname": "a hostname"
        }
      ]
    });

    let host = &json_value["data"][0]["hostname"];
    println!("Host: {:?}", host);
}
```

You can also use a [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) via [`pointer`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.39/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html#method.pointer):

```
let host = json_value.pointer("/data/0/hostname");
println!("Host: {:?}", host);
```

Comment: Do you recommend using `pointer` or using the index syntax?  Or `.get(...)`?

Comment: @JakeIreland It depends on if you expect the value to be there or not (and thus using something that could panic).

Comment: This should be the answer, except that the index does not panic according to the implementation and the docs: https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.62/src/serde_json/value/index.rs.html#175-213

Answer (score 2):

I would chain [flattened structures](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html#capture-additional-fields)

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_json::Value;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Payload {
    data: Vec<Data>,

    #[serde(flatten)]
    _: HashMap<String, Value>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    hostname: String,

    #[serde(flatten)]
    _: HashMap<String, Value>,
}

let payload: Payload = serde_json::from_str(your_string)?;
assert_eq!(payload.data.0.hostname, "a hostname");
```

Comment: There is really no need for your hashmap, funny enough this answer is the best from performance point of view. Use json::Value is very slow. But remove your useless hashmap.